# Turn on httplib logging globally from a static method in a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-requests, python-logging

I have this class which turns on verbose logging for the httplib library which requests uses. I would like to invoke it before i run any requests code and have logging turned on. However, logging is not turned on after i call it. If i take the code out of the static method and place it in a function in the main python file and run it then it works. However i would like it packaged into a class and a static method.

```
import logging
import http.client

class HttpClientUtilities:

    @staticmethod
    def enable_logging(level=logging.DEBUG):

        global http

        httpclient_logger = logging.getLogger("http.client")

        """Enable HTTPConnection debug logging to the logging framework"""

        def httpclient_log(*args):
            httpclient_logger.log(level, " ".join(args))

        # mask the print() built-in in the http.client module to use
        # logging instead
        http.client.print = httpclient_log
        # enable debugging
        http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
```

I call it like so:

```
from HttpClientUtilities import HttpClientUtilities

HttpClientUtilities.enable_logging()

#then here i run some methods from other classes which use the requests library
```

Within the enable_logging method i used global http so it should be referencing the global http object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier solution here: [urllib3 debug request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892038/urllib3-debug-request-header)

By overwriting the default debug level:

```
# You'll need to do this before urllib3 creates any http connection objects
import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 5
```